# Remote desktop timeout

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I have a PC connected to a SmartBoard which has its own PC connected to it. They are both running on Windows 7.

I am using **Chrome Remote Desktop** to connect both which happens to be in the same room. But the problem is, it keeps timing out after say 8 minutes. This has been going on for months now. But there was one time when I connected and it never timed out and I just don't know what changes was made that it won't time out anymore. The next day by the way after that, it keeps timing out again.

I know there is similar question on this one already

[How to set Chrome Remote Desktop connection to never timeout?](https://superuser.com/questions/583602/how-to-set-chrome-remote-desktop-connection-to-never-timeout)

but there is now a newer version of Chrome Remote Desktop using **[remotedesktop.google.com](http://remotedesktop.google.com)** and there could be differences now.

So, what could be the reason for the frequent timeout? I understand the security issue but again this is in the same room and the two computers frequently connect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the connection lan/wlan. 
And just in case check the energie saving option. Could be that the client goes to energie saving mode and kills the remote connection.

If you want to narrow it down, change the PC and check if it still lose connection.
Then there would be only smartboard and connection left to check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried other PC and it was still the same. As for the energy saving, I'll check but I doubt it. But thanks again for your reply.